# Extract multiple matches after a specific string or pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have the below sentence:

> we have a Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence

When using the regex in Python `(\w+)`, I am getting the below output

```
we 
have 
a 
Newliner 
Chatacter 
in 
10000 
the 
Middle 
of 
the 
sentence
```

But when I am trying to find words between 2 words using the regex `(?<=a )(\w+)`, I am not getting the desired output.

What I am getting is

```
Newliner
```

When I used the regex `(?<=a ).*`, I am getting the rest of the words as one group.

And what I need is the below words as separate groups.

```
Newliner 
Chatacter 
in 
10000 
the 
Middle 
of 
the 
sentence
```

Comment: "But when I am trying to find words between 2 words" which 2 words?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex replacement with split approach.  We can trim off the leading text up until the `a`, then split what remains.

```
inp = "we have a Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence"
words = re.sub(r'^.*\ba\b\s+', '', inp).split()
print(words)
```

This prints:

```
['Newliner', 'Chatacter', 'in', '10000', 'the', 'Middle', 'of', 'the', 'sentence']
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:**

1. With Python `re`, you need to do two steps: a) get the location from where you want to start matching, and then use `Pattern.findall` / `Pattern.finditer` to get all expected matches (see the first two snippets below)
2. With PyPi `regex` module, you can extract these matches with one go using the `\G` based regex pattern.

**`re` way**

Getting multiple matches after a specific text is a common regex question, but Python `re` has no way to do that without additional steps. That is, you need to find the *position* where you need to start extracting matches from first, and then pass this position to the [`Pattern.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) method (note it can't be `re.findall` static method as it does not accept a *`pos`* argument).

To accomplish the first step, you can use either a regex (if you need to start matching from the first/last/nth occurrence of some pattern), or simple hardcoded/literal string approach (either with slicing or using `str.find()`, etc.).

Here, it looks like you need **to start extracting matches after a whole word `a`**. In this case, **you can use a regex based approach**:

```py
import re

def extract_all_after_pattern(search_after_rx, reg, text):
    search_after = re.search(search_after_rx, text)
    if search_after:
        # print(f"Found at {search_after.start()}, searching from {len(search_after.group())}, i.e. in '{text[search_after.end()+1:]}'")
        # Found at 8, searching from 1, i.e. in 'Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence'
        return reg.findall(text, search_after.end()+1)
    else:
        return []
    
text = "we have a Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence"
search_after_rx = r'\ba\b' # Or, r'a\s', r'\sa\s', r'(?<!\S)a(?!\S)', etc.
reg = re.compile(r'\w+')
print(extract_all_after_pattern(search_after_rx, reg, text))
# => ['Newliner', 'Chatacter', 'in', '10000', 'the', 'Middle', 'of', 'the', 'sentence']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/QiaBcX).

**If** you know the string **you want to start extracting after** is not a pattern, but **a literal string**, you can use a "simpler" approach:

```py
import re

def extract_all_after_string(search_after, reg, text):
    start = text.find(search_after)
    if start >= 0:
        # print(f"Found at {start}, looking from {start+len(search_after)}, i.e. in '{text[start+len(search_after):]}'")
        # Found at 8, looking from 10, i.e. in 'Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence'
        return reg.findall(text, start+len(search_after))
    return []
        
text = "we have a Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence"
search_after = "a "
reg = re.compile(r'\w+')
print(extract_all_after_string(search_after, reg, text))
# => ['have', 'a', 'Newliner', 'Chatacter', 'in', '10000', 'the', 'Middle', 'of', 'the', 'sentence']
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/0EPFe1).

**PyPi `regex` way**

**To extract matches after a certain string with a *single regex***, you need to install **[PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)** (run `pip install regex` in your terminal) and then use the `\G` based regex (see ["Continuing at The End of The Previous Match"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html):

```py
import regex
text = "we have a Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence"
pattern = r'(?:\G(?!^)|\ba\b)\W*(\w+)'
print(regex.findall(pattern, text))
# => ['Newliner', 'Chatacter', 'in', '10000', 'the', 'Middle', 'of', 'the', 'sentence']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2aS4r/1/) and the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LU49C8IwEN37K84uTVREcROkg4OTri5BuLanCcRriIet4H@Psfim9@B9hbfYnrcpuUfoo0CkO42F0Ciwh3IgsPgiQDjT4B1ThINFwVYycwybdQaIJTi5rvME/W1ST2IhbqksAkr2ci6Llap35qjq2VV/TIOm0eYyV2ZY6KoI0bGoaXx1c9yh9@ofXcLvjdYpfQE). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\ba\b)` - either the end of the previous match or a whole word `a`
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars (this must be used to get to the next word char chunk)
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (the value returned by `regex.findall`): one or more word chars.

Answer (score -1):

Ask yourself, do you really need regular expressions? Maybe the generator function will be enough.

```
def words_after_stop_word(sentence, stop_word=None):
    for w in sentence.split():
        if stop_word == None:
            yield w
        elif w == stop_word:
            stop_word = None

sentence = 'we have a Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence'
for w in words_after_stop_word(sentence, 'a'):
    print(w)
```

Demo on [Rextester](https://rextester.com/MVRS74833).

You can also find the beginning of the stop word and break the sentence after it.

```
def words_after_stop_word(sentence, stop_word=None):
    if stop_word == None:
        l = sentence.split()
    else:
        p = f' {sentence} '.find(f' {stop_word} ')
        l = [] if p == -1 else sentence[p + len(stop_word) + 1:].split()
    return l

sentence = 'we have a Newliner Chatacter in 10000 the Middle of the sentence'
print(words_after_stop_word(sentence, 'a'))
```

Demo on [Rextester](https://rextester.com/GTEDV59833).